# Probability of combination

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

Group of $5$ people is chosen at random from $7$ people. Given that person $A$ and $B$ are both chosen or neither of them is chosen, find probability that both of them are chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways you can choose a group without person A or person B is $1$ (since there are only 5 remaining people, so there are $\binom{7-2}{5} = 1$ ways to choose a group without them).

The number of ways you can choose a group with person A and person B is $\binom{7-2}{3}= \binom{5}{3} = 10$, since you can pick 3 other people to join the group from the remaining $7-2=5$ people.

The total number of ways to choose a group of 5 people from $7$ people is $\binom{7}{5}$.

Thus, the probability of choosing a group with A and B or neither of them is $\frac{\#\text{ of ways to choose a group without A or B} + \#\text{ of ways to choose a group with A and B}}{\text{# of ways to choose a group of 5 people}} = \frac{1+10}{\binom{7}{5}} = \frac{11}{\binom{7}{5}}$ .

Now, the probability that both of them are chosen given that either both of them are chosen or neither of them are chosen is the probability that {{both are chosen} AND  {both are chosen or neither are chosen}} = {both are chosen} divided by the probability that both are chosen or neither are chosen, by the definition of conditional probability.

The probability that both are chosen is $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{7}{5}}=\frac{10}{\binom{7}{5}}$, so the probability is $\frac{\frac{10}{\binom{7}{5}}}{\frac{11}{\binom{7}{5}}}=\frac{10}{11}$.